# Pivot on Multiple Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have following data.

```
state    f_name     product     paymonth     income     expense     savings
state_1  f1         product_1   apr-2013     5000       1500        3500
state_1  f1         procudt_1   may-2013     4500       3000        1500
state_1  f1         procudt_2   may-2013     4500       3000        1500
state_2  f2         product_2   apr-2013     15000      11500       35000
state_2  f2         product_3   aug-2013     1500       500         1000
```

Pivot on paymonth column with headers like these which is desired result...

```
state    f_name   product    apr-2013_income   apr-2013_expense   apr-2013_savings   may-2013_income   may-2013_expense.....and so on for distinct paymonth
state_1  f1       product_1  5000              1500               3500               4500              3000....and so on....
state_1  f1       product_2  0                 0                  0                  4500              3000....
```

Now, the real problem is state, f_name and products must remain as columns and they are dynamic.

Also paymonth and other data is dynamic.

Need to use Pivot. I googled some examples but not getting what i want.

This is what i tried...

```
DECLARE @COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @COLS = COALESCE(@COLS + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(PAYMONTH)
FROM #DATA
GROUP BY PAYMONTH, PM ORDER BY PM --pm is last date of paymonth for ordering data in asc/desc

declare @QUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT state, product, f_name, ' + @COLS + ' FROM
(
    SELECT state, product, f_name, income, paymonth--, expense, saving,
    FROM #DATA
) X
PIVOT
(
         SUM(income)
         FOR paymonth IN (' + @COLS + ')
) P
ORDER BY state, product, f_name'
execute(@query)
```

This will give correct result for pivot on paymonth for income but i cant do it for all 3, income, expense and savings.

Tried cross apply and unpivot but failed.

Need help in this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the denormalised structure of your source table. As always, this leads to difficulties in querying.

If you normalise it using `unpivot`, then the next pivot is relatively simple...

```
select * 
from 
(
     select state,f_name,product, cost, paymonth+'_' +paytype as pp from #data
    unpivot (cost  for paytype in (income, expense, savings)) u
) up
pivot (sum(cost) for pp in 
    ([apr-2013_income],[apr-2013_expense],[apr-2013_savings],[may-2013_income] --, ....
    )
) p
```

Constructing dynamic SQL from this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: work good, the point i was missing was cost and paytype when i was trying to unpivot. Thanks...!!